# SmtpClient fails to send ical meeting invite when there's a period in Organizer's email

Tags: c#, icalendar, smtpclient, outlook-calendar

I am trying to send an Meeting Invite with C# and for some reason it will not be sent if the Organizer's email address has a period.

> ORGANIZER;CN="John, Song":mailto:song.john@company.com

It will work if I remove the period in the email address

> ORGANIZER;CN="John, Song":mailto:songjohn@company.com

My complete sample code is here.

```
public static void SendEmailString()
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("song@company.com", "Song");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("John@company.com", "John"));
            msg.Subject = "CS Inquiry";
            msg.Body = "TESTING";

            string test = @"BEGIN:VCALENDAR
            PRODID: -//Company & Com//Credit Inquiry//EN
            VERSION:2.0
            METHOD:REQUEST
            BEGIN:VEVENT
            ATTENDEE;CN=""John, Song"";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:song@company.com
            ATTENDEE;CN=""Lay, Sean"";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:lins@company.com
            ORGANIZER;CN="John, Song":mailto:song.john@company.com
            DTSTART:20171205T040000Z
            DTEND:20171206T040000Z
            LOCATION:New York
            TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
            SEQUENCE:0
            UID:a16fbc2b-72fd-487f-adee-370dc349a2273asfdasd
            DTSTAMP:20171027T215051Z
            DESCRIPTION:Request for information regarding Test
            SUMMARY:Summary 
            PRIORITY: 5
            CLASS: PUBLIC
            BEGIN:VALARM
            TRIGGER:-PT1440M
            ACTION: DISPLAY
            DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
            END:VALARM
            END:VEVENT
            END:VCALENDAR
            ";

            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.company.com");

            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(test, ct);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

            sc.Send(msg);

        }
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I looked at the iCalendar spec and couldn't find anything about period being an illegal character in Organizer's email address.

Thanks!

Comment: I just saved your string as an `ics` file, and opened it in Outlook. It loaded the meeting request with the organizer just fine. Can you be more specific about the nature of the issue? "It will not be sent" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Rian, sorry about that. I ran the SendEmailString() method in my sample console program, and I was able receive the meeting invite in my Outlook when there is no period in the Organizer's email address, and I didn't receive anything when there is period. I check the string against iCalendar validator at https://icalendar.org/validator.html and it had no error. So I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. Everything works fine when if there is no period in the organizer's email address, and I got nothing when there is period. I saved the text to .ics file (with period) and outlook opens it just fine, it just won't work through the C# console code. I googled left and right and couldn't find anything related to that.